# Add existing objects to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to add some existing `JRadioButtons` to an array of this type for later use. I have this:

```
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton4;
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton5;
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton6;
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton7;
public static javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton8;
```

These are my buttons. Then I declare this:

```
 public static JRadioButton[] seq = new JRadioButton[8];
```

And then I try to assign each button from array like this:

```
seq[0] = jRadioButton1;
```

But when I try to access it like this:

```
seq[0].setSelected(true);
```

I get a null pointer exception. I am new to Java and this is my first logic of doing this things. Any suggestions?

Comment: By default, objects are initialised to `null` unless you explicitly initialise them yourself. Have you actually initialised the `JRadioButton` objects before you try to use them?

Comment: At any point, do you state `jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your static `JRadioButton` variables *are* null references until they're assigned new `JRadioButton` objects:

```
jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton();
seq[0] = jRadioButton1;
seq[0].setSelected(true); // Won't throw
```

Comment: Are the radio buttons displayed on a form?

Comment: Yes it is. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like your radio buttons are being created elsewhere, and you're attempting to put them into the array before they been created. Creating new objects won't help, they'll simply be overwritten wherever else they're being created. I'd suggest find where they're created, and executing your code above after that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you are trying to do, reformat your code entirely:

```
int buttonsNeeded = 8;
JRadioButton[] seq = new JRadioButton[8];
for(int i=0; i<buttonsNeeded; i++) {
    seq[i] = new JRadioButton();
}

seq[0].setSelected(true);
```

This creates your required array **and** initializes each item without the need for all those declarations. And it works as well for 5-10-1000 buttons if you know what I mean.